# Search filter a column values when input is array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have a table, where i want to filter the values in the columns from input search box.

This is my earlier code where input age = 10

```
if (age_input!= '') {
    output_age += ' AND upper(\"age\") like upper(\'%' + age_input+'%\')' 
}
```

Now, i need to change the code where input age = 10,12

```
for(i=0; i < child_input.length;i++){
if (age_input!= '') {
    output_age += ' AND upper(\"age\") like upper(\'%' + age_input+'%\')' 
}
}
```

i need to get results of both 10, 12 ages

Comment: What is this search syntax for?

Comment: You shouldn't be using javascript to generate sql/db2 queries.